# how spread syntax in the reducer is different from just returning the array coming from the action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can not understand that part, i know that if i have an array like this:

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

should be the same like this:

```
const y = [...x];
```

How this can be different in redux :

I have an action like this that takes a product and cartProducts(the previous state) and check if the product exist in the cartProducts array (by comparing ids), if the product does not exist push it to the cart, if exist increment the quantity of the found product:

This is my **action**

```
export const addToCart = (product, cartProducts) => {
    if (!product.quantity) {
        product.quantity = 1;
    }
    const index = cartProducts.findIndex(p => p.id === product.id);
    if (index < 0) {
        cartProducts.push(product);
    }
    else {
        cartProducts[index] = {
            ...cartProducts[index],
            quantity: cartProducts[index].quantity + 1
        }
    }
    return {
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: cartProducts
    }
}
```

The reducer that **work**:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_TO_CART:
        return [...action.payload];
      default:
        return state;
   }

}
```

The reducer that **does not work**(cartProducts does not render properly and don't know why??):

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_TO_CART:
        return action.payload;
      default:
        return state;
   }

}
```

**How spread syntax changed everything here, the same array with same products should be returned in both cases??**

Comment: Because spread syntax is creating a new array so the subscriber knows it changed. Returning the modified original array, the subscribers won’t know it changed.

Comment: can you add that answer with some detailed explanation please??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because spread syntax is creating a new array so the subscriber knows it changed. Returning the modified original array, the subscribers won’t know it changed.

Arrays (and objects) are passed by their reference, so if you return a reference to the same array, regardless of what you inserted or removed, javascript thinks it is the same array.  This doesn't work with a reducer because, by design, subscribers to the store will only react to changes, so they'll only react if the array actually changes, and the only way to do that is to return a different (new) array.

This is why it's generally advisable to avoid mutating arrays or objects in this kind of store framework (or in general), and treat objects and arrays as immutable.

Comment: i always knew that re-rendering is done once state get changed but this is the first time to understand the real nature of change, thank you!!